# When I'm trying to build a new project with gatsby-cli, I'm getting error

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, gatsby

> ```
> ‼ Command failed: C:\projects\my-blazing-fast-site\node_modules\pngquant-bin\vendor\pngquant.exe --version
>
> ‼ pngquant pre-build test failed
> i compiling from source
> × Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
> at Promise.all.then.arr (C:\projects\my-blazing-fast-site\node_modules\execa\index.js:231:11)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! pngquant-bin@5.0.2 postinstall: node lib/install.js
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the pngquant-bin@5.0.2 postinstall script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! C:\Users\Maciek\AppDa
> ```

Answer (score 3):

For Getting Solution i follow this steps,

1. Remove Old Node Module Folder,
   Start with create fresh Gatsby Project before that install,

   ```
   npm install --global windows-build-tools
   ```
2. Then, follow Gatsby Document for creating Project,Visit https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/quick-start/

   ```
   npm install -g gatsby-cli

   gatsby new gatsby-site

   cd gatsby-site

   gatsby develop
   ```
3. Then if error shows like above we need to install externally

   ```
   npm install imagemin-pngquant@5.0.1 --save

   npm install pngquant-bin@3.1.1 --save
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried various solutions and encountered this issue while installing sharp plugin which relies on pngquant. One possible approach is to remove the sharp folder (or any other plugin that gives you the warnings) from node_modules. Then insert the following code.

```
npm config set ignore-scripts false
```

Re-install sharp / any troublesome plugin and hopefully you will get gatsby develop running. So far everything works fine on my machine.